# How to find the inverse of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse

Let the function $g$ be strictly positive (or strictly negative). Let $f\left( x\right) =\int _{a}^{x}g\left( t\right) dt$. How to find $f^{-1}\left( x\right)$ in terms of $g$?

Let's use $f\left( x\right) =\int ^{x}_{1}\sin \left( \cos t\right) dt$, with $f:\left[ -\dfrac{\pi }{2},\dfrac{\pi }{2}\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, as an example. How do I find $f^{-1}\left( x\right)$?  ($\dfrac{d}{dx}\left( f^{-1}\left( x\right) \right)$ ?)

Any explanation is much appreciated

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: It seems to be a problem that can be solved using the fundamental theorem and the inverse function theorem. Are you sure that what you need is not the value of the derivative of the inverse function at some point, for example at $x=0$?

Comment: oh yes there's a problem about the first integral. i will fix that asap

Comment: @sapotonto yes thats what i need.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the comments, you need to calculate $(f^{-1})'(0)$. The key is to employ the formula for the derivative of the inverse function provided by the inverse function theorem: $(f^{-1})'(x)=[f'(f^{-1}(x))]^{-1}$

In this case, $(f^{-1})'(0)=[f'(f^{-1}(0))]^{-1}$. Since $f(1)=0$, then $f^{-1}(0)=1$. Substituting this result, we have that $(f^{-1})'(0)=[f'(1)]^{-1}$. The value of $f'(1)$ can be obtained from the fundamental theorem: $f'(1)=\sin(\cos(1))$, so the result is:
$(f^{-1})'(0)=[\sin(\cos(1))]^{-1}$